# Retrieving data from multiple tables - SQL

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have the following tables:

Table Searches:

```
Date        Product    Search_ID
2017-01-01    Nike            101
2017-01-01    Reebok          292
2017-01-01    Nike            103
2017-01-01    Adidas          385
2017-01-02    Nike            284
```

Table Purchases

```
Date        Product    Total_sale
2017-01-01    Adidas        4
2017-01-01    Nike          1
2017-01-01    Adidas        2
2017-01-02    Nike          3
```

Each product can have multiple rows within the same day. Total number of purchases for a product for that day = sum(total_sale)

I need to find the purchase ratio per product per day, i.e. number of purchases / number of searches.

For reference, for Nike on `2017-01-01`, total number of searches is `702` while total number of purchases is `47`, giving a purchase ratio of 4`7/702 = 0.0669`

I tried:

```
select t1.product, sum(t1.Total_sale), count(t2.Search_ID)
from db.purchases t1 join db.searches
on t1.date = t2.date and t1.product = t2.product
where t1.date = '2017-01-01' and t1.product = 'Nike'
group by t1.product, t1.date
;
```

and this gives me a bizarre result:

```
 product  |  sum  | count 
----------+-------+-------
   Nike   | 32994 | 32994
```

... what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregations *before* the joins:

```
select p.product, p.sales, s.searches
from (select p.date, p.product, sum(p.Total_sale) as sales
      from db.purchases p
      group by p.date, p.product
     ) p join
     (select s.date, s.product, count(*) as searches
      from db.searches s
      group by s.date, s.product
     ) s
     on p.date = s.date and p.product = s.product
where p.date = '2017-01-01' and p.product = 'Nike';
```

Note:  You can move the `where` into the subqueries, to improve performance.  This will readily generalize to more days and products.

Answer (score 2):

The join has multiplied your resultset, you will see it when you remove GROUP BY and use * instead of your specified fields.

```
select * from db.purchases t1 join db.searches
on t1.date = t2.date and t1.product = t2.product
where t1.date = '2017-01-01' and t1.product = 'Nike'
```

You do not need to join the tables to calculate the purchase ratio:

```
SELECT     
(select sum(t1.Total_sale) from db.purchases t1 where t1.date = '2017-01-01' and t1.product = 'Nike')
/
(select count(t2.Search_ID) from db.searches t2 where t2.date = '2017-01-01' and t2.product = 'Nike')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're joining two tables that are not aggregated, so each "purchase" row is joined with each "search" row. hence your result 32994, which comes from 702 x 49.

The correct way to achieve the desired result with a join would be

```
select  t1.product, t1.total_sales, t2.search_count
from    (
          select date, product, sum(total_sales) as total_sales
          from   db.purchases
          group by date, product
        ) t1
join    (
          select  date, product, count(search_id) as search_count
          from    db.searches
          group by date, product
        ) t2
on      t1.date = t2.date and t1.product = t2.product
where   t1.date = '2017-01-01' and t1.product = 'Nike'
group by t1.product, t1.date;
```